# Simple number generator

Tags: python, iterator

How do I write a function that simply returns incrementing numbers on each call?

```
print counter() # 0
print counter() # 1
print counter() # 2
print counter() # 3
etc
```

For clarity, I'm not looking for a generator (although the answer would probably use it). The function should return an integer, not an iterable object. I'm also NOT looking for a solution involving global or otherwise shared variables (classes, function attribute etc).

See here http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/01/monads-in-python-with-nice-syntax.html for some useful insights about the matter.

Comment: You will need to store somewhere the last used number to increment. Without using global, shared variables etc the only solution would be to pass the last number where the counter returns that value + 1 but this is hardly called a solution.

Comment: You need to store the information *somewhere*, otherwise what you're suggesting is impossible.

Comment: Is this homework?  What are you using the counter for?

Comment: @thg435:  Quite honestly.  The question seems contrived with arbitrary restrictions, so that made me think homework.  But if it's not homework, knowing how you planned to use such a function would help us give better answers.

Comment: Maybe he just doesn't understand how generators work, and doesn't realize that a generator isn't limited to using in a for-loop. I'd give an example if the answer wasn't closed.

Comment: How can it be "not a real question" if it is answered appropriately?

Comment: @glglgl: Note that the last close vote is from the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short,

```
from itertools import count
counter = lambda c=count(): next(c)
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use this over `count().next`?

Comment: The lambda is a unneeded misdirection.

Comment: @S Maybe it is, but AFAICT it makes it portable between Py2 and 3

Comment: 99 % of source files would need to be passed through `2to3` anyway, and `2to3` correctly converts `count().next` to `count().__next__`, so this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to implement that function -- it already exists:

```py
counter = itertools.count().next
```

or in Python 3.x

```py
counter = itertools.count().__next__
```

More generally, if you want a callable that has additional state, there are several solutions:

1. A class:

   ```py
   class Counter(object):
       def __init__(self, start=0):
           self.count = 0
       def __call__(self):
           val = self.count
           self.count += 1
           return val
   ```
2. A mutable default argument:

   ```py
   def counter(_count=[0]):
       val = _count[0]
       _count[0] += 1
       return val
   ```
3. A closure:

   ```py
   def make_counter(start=0):
       count = [start]
       def counter():
           val = count[0]
           count[0] += 1
           return val
       return counter
   ```

   In Python 3.x, you wouldn't need the above hack using a list any more, since you could use a `nonlocal` declaration:

   ```py
   def make_counter(start=0):
       count = start
       def counter():
           nonlocal count
           val = count
           count += 1
           return val
       return counter
   ```
4. Function arguments:

   ```py
   def counter():
       val = counter.count
       counter.count += 1
       return val
   counter.count = 0
   ```
5. A generator:

   ```py
   def count(start=0):
       while True:
           yield start
           start += 1
   counter = count().next   ## or .__next__ in Python 3.x
   ```

Of course all these solution have to store the current count *somewhere*.

Comment: Note that 1 and 3 use instance state, but 2 and 4 use shared state.

Comment: @thg435: You asked for a function with state without using state.  You are right, I didn't provide that.  What's the point of this restriction?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @thg435: And the itertools suggestion isn't a closure.  It's a bound method of a `count` object.

Comment: @thg435: Pardon my bluntness, but the claim that generators store state less explicitly than, say, a closure, is utter nonsense.  They even have more state, because the whole execution frame will be kept alive, while closures only keep those cell variables that are used by nested function objects that are still around.  And finally, I did show you a way to use a generator without explicitly calling `next(generator)` -- simply bind a name to `generator.next`.

Comment: @thg435: I added an example using a generator as point 5.

Answer (score 4):

So, you want to write a function that does magic by not using any language features, right? That's nonsense. You either write a generator, or make a callable class (instance attributes are not "shared" by anything).

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = -1
    def __call__(self):
        self.n += 1
        return self.n

counter = Counter()
counter() # 0
# ...

# generator
def counter():
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1
```